# SQL Where Clause Single Quotes

Tags: sql, where-clause, quotes, clause

I’m trying to get single quotes around a large amount of text. Example

```
SELECT
DiagnosisID
FROM DiagnosisTable
WHERE DiagnosisID IN (
E01.8, E02, E03.2, E03.3, E03.8, E03.9, E89.0, 
I21.01, I21.02, I21.09, I21.11, I21.19, I21.21, I21.29, I21.3, I21.4,     
I22.0, I22.1, I22.2, I22.8, I22.9 
G30.0, G30.1, G30.8, G30.9
```

Theres about 2,300 different ID’s. Is there another way to place ‘ ‘ around the ID's? Is there another function to use?

Thanks

Comment: Add the quotes when you generate the list.  Did you really type them in manually?

Comment: You could insert those values into a table and join against it.

Comment: If the data is from a file you can insert into a table and join. If you don't want to import then excel is good at task like this with simple formulas.

Answer (score 3):

Copy your quety to any text editor (yes, even notepad) that have a find & replace function. Replace `,` with `', '` and add the firat and last `'` manually.

If you already started to add them manually, first replace `'` with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Just thought there was another functionality that would make it easier.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column A, add a formula to column B

**= "'" & A1 & "'"**

and copy the formula down. copy column B then paste value in the where clause of the SQL query .

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do. It's not graceful or elegant, but it suits my purposes.

Create a table to hold the IDs.

```
create table MyID (ID  varchar(10))
```

Create a spreadsheet and add list into column B. In column A, type the following:

`Insert into MyID values ('`

In column C type:

```
)'
```

Copy all of the columns down to the end of the list.
In column D, concatenate them A+B+C+D to get a string.
Paste the string into your SQL window and insert the lines.
Then, use it in a query:

```
`Select D.* 
FROM DiagnosisTable D 
join MyID M on D.DiagnosisID = M.ID`
```